# vue breadcrumb not set fullpaths as links

Tags: vue.js, router, quasar-framework

I'm using the following to generate a breadcrumb for my Vue app

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <q-breadcrumbs>
        <q-breadcrumbs-el v-for="crumb in crumbs" :key="crumb.id" :label="crumb.text"
                          :to="crumb.to"/>
      </q-breadcrumbs>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BreadCrump',
  computed: {
    crumbs: function () {
      const pathArray = this.$route.path.split('/')
      pathArray.shift()
      const breadcrumbs = pathArray.reduce((breadcrumbArray, path, idx) => {
        breadcrumbArray.push({
          path: path,
          to: breadcrumbArray[idx - 1]
            ? '/' + breadcrumbArray[idx - 1].path + '/' + path
            : '/' + path,
          text: path
        })
        return breadcrumbArray
      }, [])
      return breadcrumbs
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My problem is that it does not work if there more then 2 levels, then the breadcrumb removes the first part of the link and just keep last 2 paths:

For example this works:

```
domain.com/home
domain.com/home/1
```

but If I go deeper to something like this:

```
domain.com/home/1/11
domain.com/home/1/11/111
```

The breadcrumb removes home from my URL and only leave the last 2 links to 1/11 or 11/111 as paths.

with console.log(this.crumbs)

I get the following, which demonstrates better what I mean, I hope :)

```
0: {path: "home", to: "/home", text: "home"}
1: {path: "1", to: "/home/1", text: "1"}
2: {path: "11", to: "/1/11", text: "11"}
3: {path: "111", to: "/11/111", text: "111"}
4: {path: "", to: "/111/", text: ""}
```

Has someone an idea how can I fix this and always getting the full path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive changed the to part to

```
  to: breadcrumbArray[idx - 1]
    ? '/' + breadcrumbArray.map(function (e) {
    return e.path
  }).join('/') + '/' + path
    : '/' + path,
```

now all paths are fullpaths